# How to change x-axis label values for (contourf) in pylab

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting in pylab with contourf and it plots nicely. However the x-axis label values get assiged from 0 to 100 in y direction and from 0 to 1000 in x direction, since I have 1000 data points in x-direction, and 100 data points in y-direction. 
But I would like the x-axis to be labeled from -4 to 4 and the y-axis to be labeled from 0 to 1000. I just want to change the label.

```
    pylab.contourf(-pac[:,100,:])  #pac is a 3D data distribution
    pylab.colorbar()
    savefig("PAC Concentration.png")
    pylab.close()
```

Thanks in Advavance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `extent` keyword argument.

```
pylab.contourf(-pac[:,100,:], extent=[-4, 4, 0, 1000])  #pac is a 3D data distribution
pylab.colorbar()
savefig("PAC Concentration.png")
pylab.close()
```